# C++ pimpl idiom and exporting data structure

Tags: c++, struct, interface, dllexport, pimpl-idiom

I implemented the pimpl pattern to hide the implementation in my dll from the rest of the world but I'm stuck on how to hide a struct that needs to be exported out of the dll. Below is a simple representation of my problem (left out some parts).

idcom.h

```
class IDcom_impl;

class IDcom
{
public:
    IDcom_API IDcom();
    void IDcom_API createList();

private:
    std::unique_ptr< IDcom_impl > m_impl;
}
```

idcom.cpp

```
IDcom::IDcom() :
    m_impl( new IDcom_impl())
{}

void IDcom::createList()
{
   m_impl->createList();
}
```

idcom_impl.h

```
class IDcom_impl
{
public:
    struct IDcom_API ListItem
    {
       std::string var1;
       std::string var2;
    }

    IDcom_impl(){}

    void createList();

    std::vector< ListItem > m_list;
}
```

If I want to expand ListItem with another variable `std::string var3` and not break the ABI and get a list of "listitem"s out of the dll, what are my options? I know that in order for the application to know something about the "ListItem" this struct has to be exported but is that enough and is this a good design

Comment: If the `ListItem` structure is supposed to be used externally as part of the `IDcom` interface, then it should not be a member of the pimpl implementation class to begin with. You might want to rethink your design.

Comment: On the other hand, the class to hide would be a great idea to nest into the private section of your interface class...

Comment: Apart from, I don't recommend to write a C++ dll. C++ ABI varies from compiler to compiler and can even change between different versions of the *same* compiler. You cannot safely use a `std::vector` created from a dll compiled with e. g. GCC in an application compiled with MSVC. That limitation might be acceptable if you write the DLL solely for including code e. g. under LGPL into proprietary software. If you want provide the DLL for a wider range, you should provide it a pure C interface (you still can use C++ *inside*). You then can provide a C++ header-only library for convenience.

Comment: The question is controversial: how to hide something from rest of the world that I want to export to that rest of the world.

Comment: Your example is incomplete: how does the application get the _list of "listitem"s_?  What's the ABI interface for this?

Comment: Öö Tiib and all,  that's my dilemma but maybe I should have stated my question differently I don't want to hide it but expand "ListItem"  without having to recompile my application that uses it. So I can use different version of dll's with one application version

Comment: Anytime I see `new` or `malloc` and `dll` in the same thought, I shudder.

Comment: Does the application know about `ListItem`, or is there some other way it gets that data?

Comment: No the application doesn't know about it, only the dll so I guess I have to export it??

Comment: You state that you _get a list of "listitem"s out of the dll_, but you haven't shown how you're doing that.  Any proposed solution should build on that important detail.  Does the app ask for individual members?  Does it get a copy of the vector?

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm, I want to do that but I'm not sure what my options are. Sorry for the confusion but that is not what I have right now. I have stated that in my original post and not breaking ABI compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is auto generated destructor. To benefit from forward declarations it should go like this:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class IDcom_impl;

class IDcom
{
public:
    IDcom_API ~IDcom();
    IDcom_API IDcom();

    void IDcom_API createList();

private:
    std::unique_ptr< IDcom_impl > m_impl;
};
```

idcom.cpp

```
#include "idcom_impl.h"
#include "idcom.h"

IDcom::~IDcom() = default;

IDcom::IDcom() :
    m_impl( new IDcom_impl())
{}

void IDcom::createList()
{
   m_impl->createList();
}
```

Note if you do not declare destructor compiler will try to auto generate it in every translation unit where destruction can happen. To be able generate destructor compiler have to know how to destroy field `m_impl` and this means he have to know destructor of `IDcom_impl`.

As a result advantages of pimpl pattern is getting busted.

If you declare destructor it will be associated with specific translation unit which have required knowledge about `IDcom_impl` and no other translation unit has to now anything about `IDcom_impl`.

Comment: Marek R, my apologies for not delivering the complete code but the problem is not that my code doesn't compile because I have that what you suggest. The problem is in my design and I was hoping that one of you pro's could help me with that. I want to be sure that I can expand "ListItem"  struct without having to compile my application only the dll, like adding an extra variable and still that dll should work with a existing ( not recompiled ) application version.

Comment: Ok so I do not understand your question. If you have correct use of pImpl then whole purpose of it is that you can do anything with `IDcom_impl`. You can add or remove functions fields here and compatibility won't be broken as long as you make sure user of your library doesn't see implementation of `IDcom_impl`. Invalid use of forward declaration of `IDcom_impl` introduces such risk since to fix build issue you had to expose private header file or fix dtor issue. If you had to ship private header with library then you did it wrong.

Comment: Marek R, the idea is indeed to only ship IDcom.h. I want to expand the struct "ListItem" in the future but without breaking the compatibility of this dll and the application that is going to use it. I need some help with the design of this possibility...if possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it but I need to run this by you guys to make sure that I have a good design. So basically the pimpl is implemented correctly but the problem is the data structure expansion ( say adding a new member variable say var3 in original post ) that I have in the dll and should be shared with the application AND a new version of the dll ( say v2 ) should work with the current version of the app ( say v2 ) and the previous one ( say v1 ) so without recompiling the app ( hence compatibility with v1 ). I have posted only the necessary ( makes reading easier :-) ) ,  the code compiles, runs and works but is this a good design for the requirements stated above and in my original post.

idcom_global.h :

```
#if defined( IDCOM_LIBRARY )
 #define IDCOMDLL_API  __declspec( dllexport )
#else
 #define IDCOMDLL_API  __declspec( dllimport )
#endif
```

idcom.h :

```
#include "idcom_listitem.h"

class idcomImpl;

class  idcom
{
public:
    IDCOMDLL_API idcom();
    IDCOMDLL_API ~idcom();
    bool IDCOMDLL_API retrieveList( std::vector< ListItem >& list );

private:
    std::unique_ptr< idcomImpl > m_impl;
};
```

idcom.cpp :

```
idcom::idcom() :
    m_impl( new idcomImpl())
{}

idcom::~idcom() = default;

bool idcom::retrieveList( std::vector< ListItem >& list )
{
    return m_impl->retrieveList( list );
}
```

idcomimpl.h :

```
class idcomImpl
{
public:
    idcomImpl(){};
    ~idcomImpl(){};
    bool retrieveList( std::vector< ListItem >& worklist );
};
```

idcomimpl.cpp :

```
bool idcomImpl::retrieveList( std::vector< ListItem >& worklist )
{
....//implementation here
}
```

idcom_listitem.h:

```
struct IDCOMDLL_API ListItem
{
    std::string id;
    std::string lastname;
    std::string firstname;
    std::string prefix;

    //expansion of members here in the future e.g. std::string dateOfBirth;
};
```